# Shell - Refactoring a string regex that join numbers

Tags: regex, bash, shell, sed, refactoring

I am trying to refacto my script to make it readable and still usable on a single line.

My script do :

- a regex on a string (GXXRXXCXX) that get all numbers matched into an array
- a string to number for all string in the array (0X -> X)
- a join on all numbers with a **'.'** delimiter
- finally, it add a **'v'** at the start of the string

The part i am strugguling the most to refacto is the array number (3 2 1) into a join (3.2.1) without using any tmp variable.

code :

```sh
GOROCO=G03R02C01
version=v$(tmp=( $(grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]+' <<< $GOROCO | bc) ); echo "${tmp[@]}" | sed 's/ /./g')
```

process :

```
G03R02C01
03 02 01
3 2 1
3.2.1
v3.2.1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using a single `sed` you can do this:

```
GOROCO='G03R02C01'
version=$(sed -E 's/[^0-9]+0*/./g; s/^\./v/' <<< "$GOROCO")

# version=v3.2.1
```

**Details:**

- `-E`: Enables extended regex mode in `sed`
- `s/[^0-9]+0*/./g`: Replace all non-digits followed by 0 or more zero by a single dot
- `s/^\./v/`: Replace first dot by a letter `v`

---

As an academic exercise here is a pure bash equivalent of doing same:

```
shopt -s extglob
version="${GOROCO//+([!0-9])*(0)/.}"
version="v${version#.}"
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for `paste`

```
$ grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]+' <<< $GOROCO | bc | paste -s -d"."
3.2.1
```